# Assigning a const char[] do you need to put in a null term

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

We are setting a char [] to some hex values i.e.

```
char [] test1 = {0x30,0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34,0x35};
```

Then we copy it into a string using

```
string teststring(test1, sizeof(test1));
```

Is the array suppose to be null terminated? or is the way we do the assignment, C++ is smart enough to know that its null terminated and have it appended anyhow?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, although I was sure we were using it correctly, there was some discussion, apparently someone else was trying to use it as a Char* thus the problems he was having.  In the instance where I was using it, I was just using it to hold binary data, which sometimes consists of 0x00 anyhow throughout the array.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using the `sizeof` operator and supplying the length of the array, you should not need to add the `NULL`.

You can find the API for the constructors [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).  It mentions this explicitly.

As mentioned in other solutions however, if you decided to create an array of `wchar_t`s then you would need to modify your supplied length argument to the constructor as follows:

```
sizeof(test1) / sizeof(wchar_t)
```

This is because the `sizeof` operator returns the size in bytes of the target, not the number of elements.  For your current question using `char` does not have this requirement since the size of a `char` is defined by the C++ to be `1`, thus division is not needed.

Comment: just a little thing I noticed, `sizeof(test1)` is assuming `sizeof(char) = 1`, and that could not be the case...

Comment: @Diego Sevilla in C++, sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1; (per `5.3.3/1`)

Comment: So you'd probably want to change `sizeof(test1)` to `sizeof(test1)/sizeof(char)`

Comment: @Diego, @JohnMcG: what cannot be assumed is that the size of a char is 8 bits, but the standard (both C and C++) defined `sizeof(char)` to be 1 always. No need to add the `/sizeof(char)` factor there.

Comment: You are correct Diego.  I have mentioned that in the solution as well as the reasoning.

Comment: OK, sorry for the error. Yes, sizeof(char) is defined to be 1. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: How about `sizeof(test1)/sizeof(test1[0])` That way you do not need to change the type in more than one place.

Answer (score 2):

It is not null-terminated. Nulls have no special meaning for std::string.
You can do something like this freely:

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    char test1 [] = {0x30, 0x31, 0, 0x33, 0, 0x35};
    std::string teststring(test1, sizeof(test1));
    for(size_t i = 0; i<teststring.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << (int)teststring[i] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Although, of course, if I used `std::string teststring(test1);` as the constructor in this example, the resulting string would have been 2 characters long.

Answer (score -2):

Using this `string` constructor you don't need to add an extra ending 0.
However, I'd add the ending 0 just in case, or so that this variable could be used in other contexts where pointers to chars are used. In this case, the `sizeof` should be modified:

```
string teststring(test1, sizeof(test1) - 1);
```

Comment: chars always have the size 1. Any other type size is calculated relative to the size of char.

Comment: Ah, yes, I noticed that. Fixed in the response. Thanks!